# Fill 'rect' background with 2 colors in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is the current code which fills `skyblue` in the background:

```
var rect=d3.select("svg")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 1250)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("fill","skyblue");
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L77g3r32/)

I want to fill a part of the rectangle(mean of the values being the split) with a different color.

We may do something like this(in html): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ8CG/158/)

How could I do this in d3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append two `rect` to have one `rect` with two color experience. Like below

```js
var rect = d3.select("svg")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("fill", "skyblue");
 
 var rect1 = d3.select("svg")
  .append("rect")
 .attr("x",100)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

**Update**
You need to find the width of `svg`

```
var svgWidth = d3.select("svg").node().getBoundingClientRect().width; //svg width
var rect1Width = svgWidth * 40 / 100;  // 40% width of svg for rect1
```

Below is complete example

```js
var svgWidth = d3.select("svg").node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
var rect1Width = svgWidth * 40 / 100;
var rect = d3.select("svg")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width", rect1Width)
   .attr("height", 100)
   .style("fill", "skyblue");

var rect1 = d3.select("svg")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", rect1Width)
   .attr("width", svgWidth - rect1Width)
   .attr("height", 100)
   .style("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: Is that the only way? Also is there an easy way to do `40%` `width` => rect1 and the rest of it => rect2?

Comment: Calculations like? Could I use 40%? or do I have to specify a number?

Answer (score 5):

You could try to dynamically build a gradient with **"hard" stops** in the SVG's `defs` section and use this gradient on `rect` like this `fill="url(#IdOfYourGradient)"`

What I mean by **hard stops** is to define two stops for the two colors at the position of the boundary.

```
<defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="50%"/>
        <stop class="stop3" offset="50%"/>
        <stop class="stop4" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        .stop1, stop2 { stop-color: red; }
        .stop3, stop4 { stop-color: blue; }
      ]]></style>
 </defs>
```

Here's more about [gradients in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients).

Comment: This is very interesting. Could you give me a fiddle with a vertical line which divides the 'rect' into two diff colors. I am somehow not getting that example right(40% blue, 60% red).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally used:
(This is a derivative of rmoestl's answer)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="520" height="240" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
        <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
        <stop class="stop2" offset="60%"/>
        <stop class="stop3" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
      
      <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        #rect1 { fill: url(#Gradient1); }
        .stop1 { stop-color: skyblue; }
        .stop2 { stop-color: white; stop-opacity: 1; }
        .stop3 { stop-color: blue; }
      ]]></style>
  </defs>
 
  <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="500" height="200"/>
  
  
</svg>
```